# MongoDB trigger re-drive

Tags: mongodb

Is there a re-drive mechanism for MongoDB triggers in Atlas? I can not find it in Atlas UI, neither can find documentation about it

Example:

My trigger function is calling a service, if the service is down at that time I can not find a way to re-drive these failed attempts later.

AWS Lambda for example, has a Dead Letter Queue that you can re-drive later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Realm is advertised to [integrate with SQS](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/services/aws/), therefore in theory it should be possible (if roundabout) to, for example, queue something into SQS when a Realm function fails which would call back into Realm and have SQS retry for as long as the Realm callback is unsuccessful.

I haven't yet been able to locate documentation on how Realm handles failing functions and what the options are for handling failure.

Comment: I'll check if I can integrate that and make it re-try. I'll report back

Comment: Docs only have reference about calling an AWS Service from a Realm Function, but if that function fails there doesn't seem to be any explicit behavior documented on how to retry

Comment: Right, you'd need to ensure that the SQS request always succeeds.